# Clear cells from ith row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below but once its executed I need to clear all Columns from A to G from the ith row

```
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As String
Dim img As Object
Dim CommodityName1 As String, T1 As String
Dim myDir As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Worksheets("Picture").Activate
Dim shape As Excel.shape
Dim datarangeb As Range
Dim numberofcells As Integer

Set datarangeb = Sheets("Data").Range("b:b")

numberofcells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(datarangeb)
numberofcells = numberofcells * 12 + 1

For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shape.Delete
Next


j = 7

For i = 2 To numberofcells

myDir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ESTIMATING SHEETS\test\rebar shapes" & "\"
CommodityName1 = Range("a" & i)
T1 = ".png"

fNameAndPath = myDir & CommodityName1 & T1

On Error GoTo errormessage:

    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
    On Error GoTo errormessage:
    With img
       'Move and Resize Image
       .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
       .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Left
       .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Top
       .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & i).Width
       .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & j).Height
errormessage:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
Exit Sub
MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the rebar!"
End If
       
    End With
    


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


i = i + 11
 j = j + 12
Next i


i = i - 1


End Sub
```

So Im not too sure what the syntax is to clear up to the end of column G.  One way is to just clear it up to G6000 or some large number but I want the code to execute not using too much memory

Comment: `Range("A" & i &":G6000").Clear`?

Comment: thats one way of doing it but dont know if that takes up  more memory and slows it down when its executing. The other issue is the number of rows can well exceed 6000 in this case

Comment: It takes miliseconds to clear data. But sometimes when clearing data, a workbook recalculates and that can take some time. If that's your case, then you need to change workboook calculation mode to manual before clearing and the automatic again. About getting last row of data, there are, literally, **thousands** of examples in this website you can see to get the last non blank row and clear until that cell.

Comment: I just set it to 27000. Obviously the workbook doesnt go to infinity so would probably set up an instruction to the user to not exceed a certain amount of cells. I was thinking that if the case was the user got past 6000 cells it would spit out an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub schedulemacro()
Dim k As Integer
Dim data As Worksheet, Picture As Worksheet, sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Set data = Sheets("Data")
Set Picture = Sheets("Picture")
Set sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet 1")
j = 13


Picture.Activate
data.Cells(2, 2) = sheet1.Cells(2, 1)
k = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet1.Range("b:b")) - 1
sheet1.Range("a2:k" & k + 1).copy
data.Range("b2:k" & k + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


If k = 0 Then
MsgBox ("Please place data into the data sheet or export from revit!")
data.Activate
data.Range("a2:l2").Select

Exit Sub
End If


 Picture.Range("A1:G12").Select
 Selection.copy

For i = 1 To k



data.Range("a" & i + 1) = i

Picture.Range("a" & j).PasteSpecial
 


j = j + 12
Next i

j = 1

i = 2
k = k + 1

For i = 2 To k


    

Picture.Cells(j, 1) = data.Range("A" & i)

j = j + 12

Next i


Call GetPic



End Sub
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As String
Dim img As Object
Dim CommodityName1 As String, T1 As String
Dim myDir As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Worksheets("Picture").Activate
Dim shape As Excel.shape
Dim datarangeb As Range
Dim numberofcells As Integer

Set datarangeb = Sheets("Data").Range("b:b")

numberofcells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(datarangeb)
numberofcells = (numberofcells - 1) * 12 + 1

For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shape.Delete
Next


j = 7

For i = 2 To numberofcells

myDir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ESTIMATING SHEETS\test\rebar shapes" & "\"
CommodityName1 = Range("a" & i)
T1 = ".png"

fNameAndPath = myDir & CommodityName1 & T1

On Error GoTo errormessage:

    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
    On Error GoTo errormessage:
    With img
       'Move and Resize Image
       .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
       .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Left
       .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i).Top
       .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & i).Width
       .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("d" & i & ":g" & j).Height
errormessage:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
Exit Sub
MsgBox "File does not exist." & vbCrLf & "Check the name of the rebar!"
End If
       
    End With
    


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


i = i + 11
 j = j + 12
Next i


i = i - 1

Worksheets("Picture").Range("A" & i & ":i27000").Clear
End Sub
```